# Problema dependencia circular - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, .net

```
Public Class FrmMenu

    Private _modelUsuario As New Usuario.Usuario
    Private _controllerUsuario As New ControllerUsuario.ControllerUsuario
    Private _frmUsuario As New VistaUsuario.FrmUsuario

    Private _msjAlert As String

    Private Sub FrmMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DaGrViUsuarios.DataSource = _controllerUsuario.RouteGetUsuario(_msjAlert)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnAgregarUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAgregarUsuario.Click
        _frmUsuario.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DaGrViUsuarios_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DaGrViUsuarios.CellDoubleClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 AndAlso e.ColumnIndex >= 0 Then
            _frmUsuario.TextUsuarioProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
            _frmUsuario.TextNombresProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
            _frmUsuario.TextEmailProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString
            _frmUsuario.TextPasswdProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString
            _frmUsuario.CmbPerfilProp = DaGrViUsuarios.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString
            _frmUsuario.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnRefrescar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnRefrescar.Click
        DaGrViUsuarios.DataSource = _controllerUsuario.RouteGetUsuario(_msjAlert)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Esta Class FrmMenu tiene como referencia a FrmUsuario donde necesito recargar el DataGridView luego de insertar un nuevo usuario

```
Public Class FrmUsuario

    Private _modelUsuario As New Usuario.Usuario
    Private _controllerUsuario As New ControllerUsuario.ControllerUsuario
    Private _mejAlert As String

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Public Property TextUsuarioProp()
        Get
            Return TextUsuario.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextUsuario.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TextNombresProp()
        Get
            Return TextNombres.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextNombres.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TextEmailProp()
        Get
            Return TextEmail.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextEmail.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TextPasswdProp()
        Get
            Return TextPasswd.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            TextPasswd.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CmbPerfilProp()
        Get
            Return CmbPerfil.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            CmbPerfil.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub CargarCampos()
        _modelUsuario.Usuario = TextUsuario.Text
        _modelUsuario.Nombres = TextNombres.Text
        _modelUsuario.Email = TextEmail.Text
        _modelUsuario.Passwd = TextPasswd.Text
        _modelUsuario.Perfil = CmbPerfil.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmUsuario_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnEnviarFormUsuario_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnEnviarFormUsuario.Click
        CargarCampos()
        If _controllerUsuario.Validacion(_modelUsuario, _mejAlert) Then
            _modelUsuario = _controllerUsuario.RouteAddUsuario(TextUsuario.Text, TextNombres.Text, TextEmail.Text, TextPasswd.Text, CmbPerfil.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario Guardado Exitosamente!.", "Success!")
            'Aqui necesito recargar el DatagridView que esta en el otro form 
            Hide()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(_mejAlert, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

En este form necesito cargar el DatagridView pero a la hora de agregar como referencia el otro form me dice un error que esto causaria una dependencia circular

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente evito el uso  de .dll precisamente por eso, me siento más agusto sin dependencias, no obstante claro está no siempre es posible.

De todas formas puedes solucionar el problema pasando el datagrid por referencia en el constructor y guardártela fuera para poder acceder al datagrid desde el resto de funciones.

Fíjate que he agregado la variable ' _ReferenciaDataGrid '

Public Class FrmUsuario

```
Private _modelUsuario As New Usuario.Usuario
Private _controllerUsuario As New ControllerUsuario.ControllerUsuario
Private _mejAlert As String

Private _ReferenciaDataGrid As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Public Sub New(DataGrid As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.



    _ReferenciaDataGrid = DataGrid

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: me da un error en el FormMenu argument not specified for parameter 'datagridview' of  Public Sub New(DataGrid As DataGridView)